# Windows 7 access to share folder in multi domain

Tags: windows-7, domain, shared-folders

I use vpn to connect my PC to another domain.

When at this state,the vpn connection is on, but I can no longer access a share folder in another PC using the first domain credentials. It says I don't *have permissions*.

Sometimes, it will pop up and ask me to input credentials, and when I input the correct domain credentials, the access is ok.

Most of the time, there won't be a pop up and access is denied.

I think there may be some cached credentials there and the system is automatically choosing them (incorrect stored credentials).

How can I clear it, or how can I make it let me choose the domain and input credentials every time I access to a shared folder?

Comment: Cross domain authentication can be tricky and that is why I had suggest this be pushed to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only connect to specific computers in another domain you can use credential manager in Windows 7.

1. Under the Windows credential section
2. Add a Windows credential
3. First line is the computer name
4. Second line is the username in the domain\username format
5. Third line is the password.

It should supply the foreign computer with the specified credentials when you try to connect.

Comment: thank you! this cleared up some problems accessing multiple win7 computers at home (no vpn, no "domains" per se).